# yml format for inventory file...fails

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

```
---
all: 
zones:
  - name: accessswitch
    hosts:
     - name: accessswitch-x0
       ip: 192.168.4.xx

  - name: groupswitch
    hosts:
    - name: groupswitch-x1
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
    - name: groupswitch-x2
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
    - name: groupswitch-x3
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
```

Basically i have a access switch and to that switch there are many group switches connected to it...Tried already "children" but this does not work. A typical ini file works....
Also i have some variables...which do apply to all zones aka. access witch & group switches...
in the future there will be more than 1 ..multiple access switches..
....
some docs use ansible-host:...confusing..

And yes..checked the uml structure...

```
cat@catwomen:~/workspace/ansible-simulator/inventories/simulator/host_vars$ sudo ansible -i testdata.yaml  all -m  ping 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all'

cat@catwomen:~/workspace/ansible-simulator/inventories/simulator/host_vars$ sudo ansible -i testdata.yaml all -m  ping 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have yaml indentation problems which is an error (indentation in yaml is significant). Moreover, you must follow [the specific format described in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Very basically, the file is an imbrication of groups in parent/child relationship starting with the top element special group `all`. A group definition looks like:

```yaml
---
my_group1: # group name, use `all` at top level
  vars:
    # definition of vars for this group. Apply to all hosts if defined for `all`
  hosts:
    # hosts in that group (host is ungrouped if it appears only in `all`)
  children:
    # mapping of children group definitions (repeat the current format)
```

A host definition looks like:

```yaml
my_host1:
  # definition of vars specific to that host if any
```

A var definition (either for `vars` in group or for a specific host) looks like:

```yaml
my_variable1: some value
```

If I understand correctly from your example, here is how your yaml inventory should look like (`inventories/so_example.yml`)

```yaml
---
all:

  children:

    accessswitch:
      hosts:
        accessswitch-x0:
          ansible_host: 192.168.4.xx

    groupswitch:
      hosts:
        groupswitch-x1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.4.xx
        groupswitch-x2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.4.xx
        groupswitch-x3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.4.xx
```

You can then easilly see how the above is interpreted with the [`ansible-inventory` command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-inventory.html):

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/so_example.yml --graph 
@all:
  |--@accessswitch:
  |  |--accessswitch-x0
  |--@groupswitch:
  |  |--groupswitch-x1
  |  |--groupswitch-x2
  |  |--groupswitch-x3
  |--@ungrouped:

$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/so_example.yml --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "accessswitch-x0": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.4.xx"
            },
            "groupswitch-x1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.4.xx"
            },
            "groupswitch-x2": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.4.xx"
            },
            "groupswitch-x3": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.4.xx"
            }
        }
    },
    "accessswitch": {
        "hosts": [
            "accessswitch-x0"
        ]
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "accessswitch",
            "groupswitch",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "groupswitch": {
        "hosts": [
            "groupswitch-x1",
            "groupswitch-x2",
            "groupswitch-x3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The incident is not correct for the line #6. Try below please.

```
---
all: 
zones:
  - name: accessswitch
    hosts:
    - name: accessswitch-x0
      ip: 192.168.4.xx

  - name: groupswitch
    hosts:
    - name: groupswitch-x1
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
    - name: groupswitch-x2
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
    - name: groupswitch-x3
      ip: 192.168.4.xx
```

Comment: cat@catwomen:~/workspace/ansible-simulator/inventories/simulator/host_vars$ sudo ansible -i testdata.yaml all -m  ping 
[sudo] password for cat: 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'